# How do I validate Pakistan phone number in Flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter, android-studio, dart, validation

[image: Code]

I am using that code but it did not validate the Pakistan phone number.
There should be 03 at the start of the number.

Here is an example: 03007986786

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia's page about Pakistan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Pakistan#:%7E:text=International%20callers%20must%20dial%20%2B92,%27YYYYYYY%27%20is%20personal%20number.), I
would say that you have to handle numbers starting with `03` or `+92-3` or `0092-3`.

Then it should be followed by 2 digits, a hyphen and 7 digits.

According to Wikipedia, the first digit after the leading "3" should
be a number between 0 and 6 (but this might change in the future). So
you could match `[0-6]` to be fully correct or `\d` if you want to
have a less drastic control.

This leads to the following regex: `^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)92)-|0)3[0-6]\d-\d{7}$`

You can test it here and have the pattern explanation:
https://regex101.com/r/2xSWgF/2